# AspNetCore WebApi QueryString parameter is processed but browser & postman say "Server not found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

**UPDATE**: for people having the same error/behaviour see answer [stackoverflow.com/a/42813181/1155847](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42813181/1155847) - my own stupid mistake, but the error message - well **no real error message** was given actually.. So let's say, the **behaviour** was quite strange.. At least, it's **solved** now.

---

**Original question/problem**:

I'm learning to build a REST-ful service with WebAPI, you can download the code at: https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/Implementing-and-Securing-an-API-with-ASP.NET-Core/tree/master/Module02_ReadingData *~ see **note** below when cloning.

I'm having trouble with the return of a parameter when I call the GET of code below with the querystring `localhost:8088/api/camps/1?includeSpeakers=true` - both postman and browser give me back "Server Not Found", and the browser even redirects to `http://www.localhost.com:8088/api/camps/1?includeSpeakers=true`... Strange behaviour for me as the other requests, such as `localhost:8088/api/camps/1` and `localhost:8088/api/camps` just work fine.

If I debug and step through I see it's going through fine and picking up the QueryString, executing it against the database, and even hitting the `return Ok(camp);` line... But I never get anything returned?

[image]

**Fiddler**:

- Fiddler says `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.`

> Request Count:   1 Bytes Sent:      408       (headers:408; body:0) Bytes
>   Received:  717        (headers:205; body:512)
>
> ### ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
>
> NOTE: This request was retried after a Receive operation failed.
>
> ClientConnected:  14:20:36.281 ClientBeginRequest:    14:20:44.067
>   GotRequestHeaders:    14:20:44.067 ClientDoneRequest: 14:20:44.067
>   Determine Gateway:    0ms DNS Lookup:         0ms TCP/IP Connect: 0ms HTTPS
>   Handshake:    0ms ServerConnected:    14:20:44.294
>   FiddlerBeginRequest:  14:20:44.294 ServerGotRequest:  14:20:44.294
>   ServerBeginResponse:  00:00:00.000 GotResponseHeaders:    00:00:00.000
>   ServerDoneResponse:   14:20:44.537 ClientBeginResponse:   14:20:44.537
>   ClientDoneResponse:   14:20:44.538
>
> Overall Elapsed:    0:00:00.470
>
> RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
>   -------------- text/html: 512 ~headers~: 205

**Environment**:

Running on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, IIS Express, localhost port 8088, no SSL configured.

**Controller**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyCodeCamp.Data;

namespace MyCodeCamp.Controllers {     
    [Route("api/[controller]")]     
public class CampsController : Controller {
        private readonly ICampRepository _campRepository;

        public CampsController(ICampRepository campRepository) {
            _campRepository = campRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() {
            try {
                var camps = _campRepository.GetAllCamps();
                return Ok(camps);
            } catch { }

            return BadRequest();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id, bool includeSpeakers = false) {
            try {
                var camp = includeSpeakers
                    ? _campRepository.GetCampWithSpeakers(id)
                    : _campRepository.GetCamp(id);
                if (camp == null) {
                    return NotFound($"Camp with id '{id}' was not found.");
                }
                return Ok(camp);
            } catch { }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    } 
}
```

~**note** When cloning from https://github.com/pluralsight-courses/Implementing-and-Securing-an-API-with-ASP.NET-Core/tree/master/Module02_ReadingData first do a `dotnet restore` and in the `MyCodeCamp.Data` folder make sure to execute `dotnet ef database update` to init the database, otherwise you won't be able to run the sample if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

This was my **own fault** - but for people hitting the same problem, I'm answering the question here as a reference, because the error I got (see my initial question) was **not obvious** :/.

Make sure you have `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` configured on the `services.AddMvc`:

```
// Add framework services.
   services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(opt => {
            opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
              ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
    ;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a known issue with how serializaiton happens. It used to just fail by endlessly serializing loops.

Answer (score 1):

when you make the request, be sure to include the http:// before localhost otherwise fiddler will try and do a DNS request (which is why www.localhost.com is redirecting). If this doesn't work, try Postman instead of Fiddler. I find it easier.

Comment: I've been using postman indeed, and used the http prefix indeed. `http://localhost:8088/api/camps/1` runs fine, it's when I'm running `?includeSpeakers=true` added to it the response fails. The request goes through to the "OK" and the closing brace. I ran your "After" sample code, and that worked fine, but uses the 1.0.3 & 1.0.2 libraries + xproj. Whilst I started in VS2017, IDK if that has something to do with it - IISExpress that comes with VS2017 maybe needs other configuration? I'll try and restart in Vs2015 and see if I have the same issue. Thanks for your help nonetheless!

Comment: see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42813181/1155847 - my own stupid mistake, but the error message was quite strange (well there was no error :))

Comment: @ShawnWildermuth I've been following your pluralsight course, but have a question, hope you can help me with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764279/angularjs-ngroute-not-serving-desired-home-page