# AngularJS: ngRoute not serving desired home page

Tags: angularjs, routes, asp.net-core, ngroute

I have no idea why my root (home page) isn't routing/displaying correctly.

Here's my ASP.Net Core project file directory setup:

[image: ASP.Net Core Project File Structure]

Here's my `MapRoute` declared in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
{
    config.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
    );
});
```

In my `AppController.cs` (default controller):

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Here's my `Views -> App -> Index.cshtml`:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div>
    <h3>Application Home Page</h3>
</div>
```

Here's my `Views -> Shared -> _Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="moveinScheduler">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/loginController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-view>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('moveinScheduler', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "index.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            controller: "loginController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
        });

    });
```

Here's `index.html` located in `wwwroot`:

```
<h3>The Home Page</h3>
<p>Home Page paragraph text.</p>
```

---

**When built/rendered:**

Here's the result when I launch in Chrome:

[image: Rendered View]

And here's what shows when I `view page source`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="moveinScheduler">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Rest of the head shown above -->
</head>
<body ng-view>
    <div>
        <div>
    <h3>Application Home Page</h3>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Weirdly enough, if I select `Inspect Element` for the text "Move In Application" on the "home" page, here's what I see:

[image: Inspect element error]

It's inserting a title and meta tag inside of the body.

*Just to be clear* - I was hoping the home page would be exactly what `index.html` has inside of it.

If anyone has a clue, please help. It'd be great to get the proper content from `index.html` to show on the Home Page.